# How to make priority on jQuery click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have buttons in my HTML template which have used a few implementations of jquery. The code is like this:

```js
// template
$('.myClass').click(()=>{
  $('#myTarget').css('background-color','green');
});

// my work
$('#myId').click(()=>{
  $('#myTarget').css('border','5px solid red');
});
```

```css
#myTarget {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTarget">Test</div>
<br />
<button id="myId" class="myClass">Change</button>
```

As you can see, the targeted div will make some changes in its border and background color. The question is not about how to change the value of CSS property, but I want to make jquery (my work) only execute the function that I created **without removing the class or removing the jquery template** of the button element, so when it clicked, only the border of that div changes. How can I make a jquery priority like that?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you suppose this to work? I mean when should the border be change and when should the background be change?

Comment: I want to disable background change but without removing the class of button because I need CSS related to the class, so it just only changes the border of the div.

Comment: Okay, and what s the purpose of `$('.myClass').click(()`? is there any other element that has the same class `.myClass` and on their click, you change the background of `myTarget`?

Comment: Yes, another element background will change, but `#myTarget` don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not()` which will only work with the matching element.

Here is the demo in which the background will change only if the clicked element has `.myClass` but does not have the `#myId` and the border will change only if the clicked element has `#myId`.

```js
let randomColor = () => '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

// Will only work with the elements which has .myClass but not #myId
$('.myClass').not('#myId').click(() => {
  $('#myTarget').css('background-color', randomColor())
});

// Will only work with the elements which has #myId
$('#myId').click((e) => {
  $('#myTarget').css('border', '5px solid ' + randomColor());
});
```

```css
#myTarget {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="myTarget">Test</div><br><br>
  <!-- Element with both, id and class -->
  <button class="myClass" id="myId" >Change Border</button>
  <!-- Element with only class -->
  <button class="myClass">Change Background</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.off()` to remove other click event listeners currently attached to the button.

```js
$('#myId').off('click').click(()=>{
  $('#myTarget').css('border','5px solid red');
});
```

Comment: Cool! how about implementing this code without jQuery?

Comment: @Jordy Is the template part still using jQuery or not?

Comment: using jquery, but I just wonder if this way implement only in javascript

Comment: @Jordy You can use event capturing then. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k8tuwpmg/